# Depth-first traversal of a graph starting at a vertex

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, depth-first-search

Following code was provided for us to build on. I am seeing issues with my depth first algorithm. I get a `nullpointerException` at `vList[0].visited = true;` in my dfs method. In class `Vertex`, the variable visited seems to be just there. I suspect that is the problem. How can I make the depth first traversal work. Thanks. Below is the code.

```
public class Graph
{
   private final int MAX_VERT = 5;

public int [][] adjMat;   // 2D adjacency matrix representation of graph

public Vertex vList []; //List of vertices

public StackX stack;

    public Graph ()
    {
    vList = new Vertex [MAX_VERT];
    adjMat = new int [MAX_VERT][MAX_VERT];

    stack = new StackX();

    for(int y=0; y<MAX_VERT; y++)      // set adjacency
           for(int x=0; x<MAX_VERT; x++)   //    matrix to 0
          adjMat[x][y] = 0; 

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
     /*
      * The matrix below corresponds to the following weighted graph
      * that contains one unidirectional edge and remaining edges are
      * bi-directional:
      *
      *         1
      *     A +-----+ C
      *     + \     |
      *     |  \    |
      *     |   \2  | 4
      *     |8   \  |
      *     |     \ |
      *     |      \|
      *     +       +
      *     B       D
      *     \       ^
      *     6\      | 2 (This is a unidirectional edge from E -> D only)
      *       \ E+--+   (All the rest of the edges are bi-directional)
      *
      */
        int graph[][] = {
         /* A   B   C   D   E        */
            {-1,  8,  1,  2, -1}, /* A */
            { 8, -1, -1, -1,  6}, /* B */
            { 1, -1, -1,  4, -1}, /* C */
            { 2, -1,  4, -1, -1}, /* D */
            {-1,  6, -1,  2, -1}  /* E */
        };

        Vertex v[] = new Vertex[5];            
    }

    static void add_neighbour(Vertex v, int graph[])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {
            String n = "";

            switch(i)  {
                case 0: n = "A"; break;
                case 1: n = "B"; break;
                case 2: n = "C"; break;
                case 3: n = "D"; break;
                case 4: n = "E"; break;
            }

            if (graph[i] != -1)  {
                v.add_neighbour(new Neighbour(v.get_label(), n, graph[i]));
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    public void displayVertex(int v)
    {
        System.out.print(vList[v].label);
    }

 //Depth First Search
    public void dfs(int [][] adjMat)  // depth-first search
    {                                 // begin at vertex 0 
        vList[0].visited = true;  // nullpointer here when compiling
        displayVertex(0);         // display it
        stack.push(0);            // push it

        while( !stack.isEmpty() )      // until stack empty,
        {
         // get an unvisited vertex adjacent to stack top
            int v = getAdjUnvisitedVertex(stack.peek());
            if(v == -1)                    // if no such vertex,
                stack.pop();
            else                           // if it exists,
            {
                vList[v].visited = true;  // mark it
                displayVertex(v);                 // display it
                stack.push(v);                 // push it
            }
        }  // end while

     // stack is empty, so we're done
        for(int j=0; j<MAX_VERT; j++)          // reset flags
            vList[j].visited = false;
    }  // end dfs 

 //returns an unvisited vertex adj to v
    public int getAdjUnvisitedVertex(int v)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<MAX_VERT; j++)
            if(adjMat[v][j]==1 && vList[j].visited==false)
                return j;
        return -1;
    }  // end getAdjUnvisitedVertex()
}

class Vertex  
{
    private String label;
    private PriorityQueue<Neighbour> neighbours;
    private boolean visited;

    public Vertex(String l) 
    { 
        label = l;
        neighbours = null;
        visited = false;
    }

    public void add_neighbour(Neighbour n) 
    {
        if (neighbours == null)
            neighbours = new PriorityQueue<Neighbour>();
        neighbours.add(n);
    }

    public Neighbour remove_neighbour() 
    {
        Neighbour n = null;

        if (neighbours.size() > 0)  {
            n = neighbours.peek();
            neighbours.remove(n);
        }

        return n;
    }

    public String get_label() { return label; }

    public String toString()
    {
        String s = "Vertex: " + label + "\n";

        s += " Neighbours: \n";

        Iterator<Neighbour> itr = neighbours.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext())  {
            Neighbour n = itr.next();
            s += n;
        }

        return s;
    }
}

class Neighbour implements Comparable<Neighbour>
{
    private String source;
    private String destination;
    private Integer weight;

    public Neighbour(String s, String d, int w)
    {
        source = s; destination = d; weight = w;
    }

    public int compareTo(Neighbour o)
    {
        if (this.weight < o.weight) return -1;
        else if (this.weight > o.weight) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "  " + destination + ", weight: " + weight + "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Post real code. This one does not compile at all.
Where's declaration of `vList`?
Where's declaration of `adjMat`? How do you access private variables like `label` or `visited`
from another class.

That's a really sloppy way to ask a question.

Anyway, if you create your `vList` like `vList = new Vertex[5]` (looking at declaration of `v` in `main`), know that this allocates only the array, and the references it contains are null. You will have to allocate them as well, something like `vList[0] = new Vertex()`.

Comment: Sorry Chill, I added the declarations. Anything else you wanna add?

Comment: @dogbern, well, read my answer to the end :) In Java, you don't have arrays of objects, you have arrays of *references to objects*. Besides creating the array, you have to create each object, that the array refers to.